# Nodes inside Cisco VPN. Incoming SSH requests allowed. But can't initiate an outbound SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, vpn, firewall, cisco

I've a gateway-to-gateway VPN setup between my Linksys RV042 router and a Cisco VPN.

I am able to SSH into any of the machine inside the VPN from my network. But none of the machines inside the VPN can initiate an SSH into my network. It seems they've blocked even all ping requests to my network gateway.

This is the requirement: I have scripts that SSH into the machines inside the VPN and run a long mysql query. The query generates an output to a file. The time that these queries take is variable. So I have a loop in my machine that periodically SSHes into the VPN machine and checks if the query has finished, and pulls the generated file using SCP.

I need to simplify it thus: The script will run at the machine inside the VPN, and when the query completes, it will SSH into my machine and pushes the generated file.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with those Linksys routers.  If they run a standard IOS, my guess would be that you do have some sort of ACL (firewall) in place.  There could be any sort of combination of Inbound or Outbound ACLs on different interfaces, and it might not be obvious because they might also be ip inspection enabled to allow certain return traffic.

I would need to see a config, or a simplified version of it (with public IPs changed) to be able to help you more I think.